# JavaScript: Getting handle to the element closing the modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Is there a way to get the handle of the page element which closed the modal popup? I figured through other post and search that "hidden.bs.modal" does not hold the source in "event.relatedTarget". I did work around the issue by other means as in storing the close button id in some hidden component. But I am looking at a cleaner approach.

Thanks

Comment: not totally clear what you are needing but nothing preventing you adding your own delegated click handler just to register whatever information you need

Comment: My scenario is, there are many buttons within the modal popup which can close the popup itself. But once I close the popup, I need to take different actions based on the button which triggered the popup close. The issue is, I need to wait until the popup closes.

Comment: add a data attribute to the buttons and read that when clicked